# Binary representation of a number, why so

Tags: c++

```
int DecimalToBinary (int number){
    int binary = 0, remainder = 0, i = 1;
 
    while (number != 0){
         remainder = number % 2;
         number /= 2;
         binary += remainder * i;
         i *= 10;
      }
    
    return binary;
 
}
```

There is a function that represents numbers from decimal to binary. With the first two lines of the while loop everything seems clear, but then, I don't understand why we need binary += remainder * i, and why i *= 10.

Please explain why this is the case.

Comment: If I have a number, e.g. 11 (eleven). And I want to add the digit 2 to it, It's 11 * 10 + 2 = 112.

Comment: Because it represent the `binary` in `int` format. So each *bit* which is a digit actually. That's why `remainder * i` since it appends the digits to the left side.

Comment: This is producing a number that looks like the binary representation of the input, if printed with decimal base. To produce e.g. 5, i.e. `0b101` that's `((1*10)+ 0)* 10 + 1` or `1 * 100 + 0 * 10 + 1 * 1`

Comment: Thank you! It's a little clearer now

Comment: Usually when I convert an `int` to a binary representation I used a `std::string` as the result type.

Comment: Binary, decimal, etc. are names for **text representations** of values. The code in the question is not producing a text representation; it's producing a value whose decimal representation looks like the binary representation of the original value. If that sounds confusing, it's because it **is** confusing. It muddles value and representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although comments have already explained the answer. Consider the following number i.e. abcd. This number can also be represented as
`a*1000+b*100+c*10+d`. This is the only purpose of line `binary += remainder * i;` and after every iteration we are multiplying `i` by 10 to increase the multiple. Hope it answered your query.